# CDN and varnish with different ESI: tag name

Tags: varnish, akamai

we are using, akamai, and they have `esi:` - and we also use `esi:` directly in varnish.
now i would love to have some `esi`'s resolved in varnish and some in the CDN.

however, i don't see a way to change the tag name like `<cdnsi:` on the CDN itself.
is there a way inside varnish todo that? - we could then choose, the tag to decide where we want the ESI to happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the open-source version of varnish (you could with the Enterprise one though). However, you could tweak the open-source code and recompile to act on a different tag.